# Combine row after used group by in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created query like

```
SELECT COUNT(CurrentSlideId) AS attempts,
       CurrentSlideId,
       UserLessonProgressId,
       IsHint
FROM  UserAnswers
WHERE (UserID = 169494)
  and UserLessonProgressId=218629 
GROUP BY UserLessonProgressId, CurrentSlideId, IsHint
ORDER BY UserLessonProgressId, CurrentSlideId
```

and output of above query looks like

[image]

now i want to combine last 2 row in one row like

Attempts=2 currentSlideId=19328 UserLessonProgressId=218629 and **IsHint=1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your query, but do `MAX(IsHINT)` and remove that column from `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS attempts,
       CurrentSlideId,
       UserLessonProgressId,
       MAX(IsHint)
FROM  UserAnswers
WHERE UserID = 169494
  and UserLessonProgressId = 218629 
GROUP BY CurrentSlideId, UserLessonProgressId
ORDER BY CurrentSlideId, UserLessonProgressId
```

Comment: i think it will work but IsHint column is bit data type column so i need to convert first

Comment: You do? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It is throw exception like "Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator." can u change accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

```
                        SELECT        COUNT(CurrentSlideId) AS attempts, CurrentSlideId, UserLessonProgressId, max(case when IsHint=1 then 1 else 0 end) hint
                        FROM            UserAnswers
                        WHERE        (UserID = 169494) and UserLessonProgressId=218629 
                        GROUP BY UserLessonProgressId, CurrentSlideId
                        ORDER BY UserLessonProgressId,CurrentSlideId
```